# Is it possible to produce "tilt-shift" effect in Mathematica?

Tags: image-processing

I attempted to produce a kind of miniature faking look from a street scene photo. I tried to
shift the perspective lines close to parallel to each other to obtain such effect. However, the result looks ugly. Is there a better way to do it?

This is the original photo.

[image: This is the original photo.]

This is the result from the code below.

[image]

```
im = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkqJW.jpg"]

pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0.25, 0},  {0.25, 1}, {0.5, 0}, {0.5,1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1} };
imgcol = BSplineFunction[ImageData[im ], SplineDegree -> 1];
Manipulate[
  Module[{f},
   f = BSplineFunction[Partition[pts, 2], SplineDegree -> 1, 
    Method -> {"Extrapolation" -> "Clamp"}]; 

  ParametricPlot[
   f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
   ColorFunction -> (imgcol[1 - #4, #3] &),
   MaxRecursion -> 0,
   PlotPoints -> ControlActive[20, 100],
   Mesh -> None, 
   Epilog -> { Gray, Opacity[.7], Line[Partition[pts, 2]]}, 
   ImageSize -> {300, 300},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.01],
   FrameTicks -> None
   ] 
  ],
 {{pts, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0.25, 0},  {0.25, 1}, {0.5, 0},  {0.5, 1}, 
   {1, 0}, {1, 1} }}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, Locator },
 TrackedSymbols :> {pts}
 ]
```

Answer (score 8):

“Tilt-shift” effect depends on the mask. Here is a full blown app with [downloadable source code](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/downloadauthornb.cgi?name=DigitalTiltShiftPhotography):

[**Digital Tilt-Shift Photography**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DigitalTiltShiftPhotography/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was always under the impression that a tilt-shift effect was achieved by blurring the top and bottom of a picture.  This is supposed to imitate a shallow depth of field.

```
mask = Image @ Table[With[{c = 150 - 50 x/300}, Abs[y - c]/c], {y, 300}, {x, 300}];
ImageFilter[Mean@Flatten@# &, image, 5, Masking -> mask]
```

[image: tilt]